# Storing message handles in an std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Message&& m)>> and invoking for derived message

Tags: c++, c++17

Logically it is not possible to store a derived message type's handler in an std::map using the base message type as the handler's parameter type.

For example having:

```
public:
    template <typename TMessage,
              typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TMessage, DerivedMessage1>::value
                                      || std::is_same<TEvent, DerivedMessage2>::value
                                      || std::is_same<TEvent, DerivedMessage3>::value>::value>
    ::type* = nullptr > void subscribe(std::function<void(TMessage&&)> cb)
    {
        handlers_.emplace(TMessage.GetTypeName(), std::move(cb));
    }

private:
    void handle_message(std::string& json) const noexcept 
    {
        auto message = to_message(json);
        auto it = handlers_.find(message.name());
        if (it != handlers_.end()) {
            it->second(message);
        }
    }
    
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(BaseMessage&)>> handlers_;
```

where DerivedMessage(1,2,3,X) inherit from BaseMessage.

Is there a way to achieve something analogous to this?

Comment: The fundamental issue is that your function cannot accept `BaseType` as input parameter. How do you intent to deal with the issue? Dynamic cast and throw when fails? Static cast and hope for the best?

Comment: `std::variant` could be an option I guess but an ugly one I guess

Comment: You can always store the handle in `std::any` and use `any_cast` to figure out whether the conversion from `std::any` to original handle is correct. It is efficient unlike dynamic cast.

Comment: `std::variant` is a better solution but still ugly I believe. It is a better version of `std::any` in every respect including performance

Comment: Why is variant "ugly"?

Comment: because I need to list all the allowed types which is not that bad but I have to re-list for `subscribe`. A solution would be declaring the list of allowed types and re-use for both `subscribe` and `std::variadic`

Comment: `std::variant` is good solution when there is a fixed number of types messages. From my understanding, you don't actually have a limited number of types of messages. Difference in performance is insignificant compared to calling a dynamic function. `std::any` doesn't perform dynamic cast.

Comment: You can definitely use a single list and use it for both `subscribe` and `std::variant`. Say you define a tuple of all of these types, then you just have to define various type traits that convert the tuple to variant and "same as one of types of the tuple".

Comment: If you have a bounded set of message types, variant is a good fit. You can re-use the same list. e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/6YoMdoh1M